Index of spatial variability
I have a geographical area, divided in municipalities. Each municipality has the count of a disease occurrences. The procedure is replicated four times, for four diseases (we can call them A, B, C, D). So I have four maps with four geographical distributions for four diseases.
The question is how much these diseases are clustered and if there is an index that measures this. I know there is Cluster Analysis, that identifies clusters, but the question is how much are they clustered?
So the question is if there is some sort of index that measures spatial variability, like a "clustering index" A = 27, B = 15, C = 8, D = 1.

You're looking for a model that includes an estimate for spatial correlation. I googled for some sources, and via https://hughst.github.io/week-7/, which directly addresses your question, I also came across Moran's I, a measure of global spatial autocorrelation. Perhaps look at https://geodacenter.github.io/workbook/5a_global_auto/lab5a.html for more on that.

Is there a way to assess the statistical significance of the difference between two Moran's I?
